# Transform collection of items with another collection inside in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, inline-functions

I have a collection of items. And each item has another collection inside.

To transform the first collection I'm using mapNotNull.
I'm trying to achive something like this:

```
data class QuestionData(        
        val items: List<Question>
)

val questions = listOf(
        QuestionData(0, emptyList()),
        QuestionData(1, listOf(Question(2, emptyList()))),
)

fun convertItem(item: QuestionData): QuestionEntity {
    return QuestionEntity(item)
}


val result: List<QuestionEntity> = questions.mapNotNull {
    convertItem(it)
    it.items.forEach {it2-> convertItem(it2) }
}
```

but this is not working.

Comment: have you tried flatMap?

Comment: I don't think `flatMap` would be useful if OP goal is not to flatten initial collection

Comment: What is the first convert doing?

Answer (score 0):

The body of lambda that you pass to `mapNotNull` function doesn't return the initial item, since `forEach` returns `Unit` as the last statement in lambda body, so the end result is List<Unit>.

You should return `it` from `mapNotNull` in order for this to work

For example:

```
data class Question(
        var someCounter: Int,
        val items: List<Question>
)

val questions = listOf(
        Question(0, emptyList()),
        Question(1, listOf(Question(2, emptyList()))),
)

fun convertItem(item: Question) {
    item.someCounter++
}

val result = questions.mapNotNull {
    convertItem(it)
    it.items.forEach { it2 -> convertItem(it2) }
    it
}
```

Even though it's not very idiomatic code, but something to start with

Comment: Why not

`questions.filterNotNull().map { convertItem(it).copy(items = it.items.map {item -> convertItem(item)}) }`

Comment: Yea, that's definitely an option. In case you know for sure that you want to copy the whole object to mutate one property or nested objects are immutable by its nature

Comment: That does not work. The last "it" is not the same type than return type of convert function.